# Creating a Session with FASTAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, fastapi

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import pyrebase
import firebase_admin
from pathlib import Path

import sys
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
sys.path.append(str(BASE_DIR))

from firebase_admin import auth
from config.config_settings import get_settings,get_firebase_auth
from database.mongoHandler import MongoDBHandler
from models.user import UserLogin,UserRegister


# Create an instance of the FastAPI router
authRouter = APIRouter()
settings = get_settings()
firebase_config = get_firebase_auth()
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebase_config)
mongo = MongoDBHandler()

# Initialize Firebase Admin SDK with credentials
firebase_admin.initialize_app(firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate(settings.FIREBASE_ADMIN_CREDENTIALS))



# Define a route for user registration
@authRouter.post("/register")
async def register_user(data: UserRegister):
    try:
        # Create a new user in Firebase Authentication
        user = auth.create_user(
            email=data.email,
            password=data.password
        )
        mongo.insert_one_document({
            "user_fullname": data.user_fullname,
            "email" : data.email
        })
        return {"message": "User registered successfully", "uid": user.uid}
    except auth.EmailAlreadyExistsError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Email already registered")
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Registration failed")


@authRouter.post("/login")
async def login(data: UserLogin):
    try:
        user = firebase.auth().sign_in_with_email_and_password(
            email = data.email,
            password = data.password,
        )
        jwt = user['idToken']
        return JSONResponse(content={'token': jwt}, status_code=200)
    except Exception as e:
        # Return the error message in the response
        return HTTPException(detail={'message': str(e)}, status_code=400)
```

I am using a FastAPI app as shown above and want to implement complete authentication on the same. I am new to firebase and Fastapi and I was trying to find a way to store teh session state of a user that is logged in at the moment. Flask gives a session wherein I can store the details of the user

I did not want to send the JWT token every single time to make a request to the backend, and I was wondering if there was a better way in storing the user credentials instead of trying to do
`user = auth.verify_id_token(jwt)` every single time to get the details of the user

Comment: Did you try adding middleware to fastapi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you an overall high level view, you can store the user's session state without sending the JWT token with every request by using `sessions` and `cookies`.

When a user successfully `logs in or registers`, you generate a `JWT token`.
You can also include add on in the token that describe the user's session
Once you generate the `JWT token`, you can store it in a `secure HTTP-only cookie` on the client-side.

*- This cookie should be encrypted and secure to prevent tampering.*

You can set an `expiration time` for the cookie to ensure it's not valid indefinitely.( represent the session duration)

you should create a `middleware in FastAPI` that runs before every request to secure endpoints, where

- you can verify the JWT token stored in the cookie and decode it.
- check the token's expiration date to ensure it's still valid.
- If the token is valid, you can access the user's information and continue with the request

For example :

```
from fastapi import Request, HTTPException

async def verify_token(request: Request):
    # Extract the JWT token from the cookie
    token = request.cookies.get("auth_token")

    
   if not token:
       raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Not authenticated")

   try:
       # Verify and decode the token using Firebase Admin SDK
       user_info = auth.verify_id_token(token)
       # Check if the token is still valid
       if user_info.get('exp') < time.time():
           raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Token expired")
       # If the token is valid, you can access user information
       request.state.user = user_info

   except Exception as e:
       raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid token")
   
app.add_middleware(verify_token)
```

***Note** : Securing session data in cookies requires careful handling of the cookies, ensuring they are HTTP-only, encrypted, and have a reasonable expiration time*

Comment: This is a great answer! if i am not wrong i need to use a `call_next()` somewhere right? 

also how can I add this middleware for every other endpoint other than `/login` or `/register`?